# React Native - text with background and a gap between multiple lines

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I m trying to do this effect on react-native

[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiEo1.png)

[Obtained result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rO9gx.png)

This is my code but i actually miss the space between the line.

```
<Text>
    <Text style={{color: '#fff',  fontWeight: '600', fontSize: 26, backgroundColor: 'blue' }}>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </Text>
</Text>
```

Comment: I couldn't recreate the desired behavior strictly with styling the text. I think you will have to get creative to make this work and I'm not so sure how robust those options may be. If you use fixed type font, you could calculate the line breaks and break them into separate <Text> components. Or perhaps if you can calculate the # of lines the text will occupy, you could put an absolute positioned empty view with white background to simulate the effect. I don't think either of these are great solutions but perhaps I may have given you some ideas.

Comment: Its actually quite easy to reproduce OP's desired result with several different solutions available...

Comment: @webdevil did you manage to solve this problem?

Comment: @WebDevil did you manage?..

Answer (score 1):

Using `lineHeight` in your styling should do what you're looking for:

```
<Text>
<Text style={{color: '#fff',  fontWeight: '600', fontSize: 26, backgroundColor: 'blue', lineHeight: 20 }}>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
</Text>
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, i have tried your code but it only enlarge "the padding" between the lines but they are still attached.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this effect using a solution similar to what Travis White suggests above. 
[Image of effect in action](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/dbzPFX2Tly2c-9AUzGZB3003sIy48jrZIxZKUohzGOVi0_iDgqvt7Hjy-3QU14c4HNQj53DXMOBIIQ0bUiyM1HKzeTUQiF3H7HyXl9JKOfMq7KVfbedfxrBlroGOd8OPUaNuRionYUL9P3K_fuX7Bs0KWOrvJoO9hTgPPQIK2y-wiWCcpBuHglrZCJumKMx6yc6EMTwHbI2vVxarc72GvZ-DOYAKU38kUhbMoQYaZ3fr8qWRFOhUAe5UT8ZECLnhQ9usloVzbsIRNIZRSLX2xW7cKqZZbiljc2n_iW2GfxrvGTGIsRBXUJnWp6DkgIhM3vBDX_osTKCilzQC5CU_bje5bbdx0ECel3EcM5U1GXvrax4-poBc0TncfE2d9HW4r_2gMjch3AsvMnaso182PjqEx3iDhKQQWEpRzBlvdzd9jo5sSuCHvxQjXZ9kaAqHwhy5H81HSjWmNEZghe_YGl4jR_GcFzGjFr5UStCGtOR1n70a5MPlBb1HTpzFtHArx3MQ3Gz4u2y7ja9FR-s2MDtUF6MCydm4W-fxn_QqK-OxIn07oggkC_9JC8intVqmg0VjGsyK4R7g0Q0VvBoZWBdIC8qBZ27qw-gljy02=w309-h626-no)

It is by no means a perfect solution, and I'm almost certain there are use cases that I am not handling for, but here it is:

```js
class HighlightText extends Component {
    state = { lines: [] };

    renderLines() {
        let textString = this.props.children;
        // splitOn is integer value. Enter expected max char count per line as prop
        const splitOn = this.props.splitOn;
        // Adds space to end of string, preventing cutoff of last word
        const singleSpace = ' ';
        textString = textString.concat(singleSpace);
        const numOfLines = Math.ceil(textString.length / splitOn);
        let lineStart = 0;
        let lineEnd = textString.slice(0, splitOn).lastIndexOf(' ');
        let fakeLineEnd = lineStart + splitOn;
        /* multiplying x2 to handle for awkward splits before very long words
         that can push content beyond the above calculated numOfLines */
        for (i = 0; i < numOfLines * 2; i++) {
            let line = textString.slice(lineStart, lineEnd);
            // Adds spaces to start and end of already populated lines for visual padding
            if (line.length > 0) {
                line = singleSpace + line + singleSpace;
                this.state.lines.push(line);
            }
            lineStart = lineEnd + 1;
            fakeLineEnd = lineStart + splitOn;
            lineEnd = textString.slice(0, fakeLineEnd).lastIndexOf(' ');
        }
        return this.state.lines.map((line, i) => 
            <View
                key={i}
                style={{
                    marginTop: this.props.marginTop,  
            }}
            >
                <Text>
                    <Text 
                        style={{ 
                            fontSize: this.props.fontSize,
                            color: this.props.color,
                            backgroundColor: this.props.backgroundColor
                        }} 
                    >
                            {line}
                        </Text>
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                {this.renderLines()}
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```